# Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded - Google Cloud Storage PHP

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to Upload and Download files from Google Cloud Storage. There is a strange error i get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message
>   'Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded' in (....)

This happends on Upload function, Download works perfectly. This is how i Upload files to GCS:

```
$source = 'C:\Users\*****\Desktop\Marathon API v26.pdf';
        $objectName = 'marathon-api.pdf';
        $bucketName = '*******';
        $storage = new StorageClient();
        $file = fopen($source, 'r');
        $bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
        $object = $bucket->upload($file, [
            'name' => $objectName,
            //'type' => 'application/pdf'
        ]);
```

I think there is something in `$file` that causes this. I tried adding `utf8_encode($file)` but with no luck. Someone encountered this error before?

Answer (score 0):

So I have replicated the procedure using the same php sample code and it seems to be working properly on my end. May I suggest investigating your **$source** path and verify whether that path contains any **invalid UTF-8** character sets. Also, you can try troubleshooting on your end by providing a relative path instead of an absolute one for your pdf file within the code.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem, and the problem was that the filename has an **invalid character** in it.

In my case, it was the "registered" character (the circle with the 'r' in it). I don't know how the user got that filename written that way in the first place, but that was the problem.

So there must be a way to identify when a filename has this condition (using PHP) and set a modified filename for the cloud upload but I don't know what that would be. Investigating now...